# Package could not be found

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, .net-core, .net-5

I'm trying-out C# and .NET 5 for the first time, but I'm having trouble importing packages.
First of all I'm using VCode as my IDE and installed C# Extension (and enabled: Omnisharp: Enable Import Completion).
When I write a function using for example List, I don't get a recommendation to import:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
```

It also doesn't recognize other classes in my project. Even when I import manually for example:

```
using WebApp.Model.Item;
```

I get an error like this:

> The type or namespace name 'Item' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) C:\Users\ljhha\Documents\IT\C\WebApp\WebApp\WebApp.csproj

I also trying the same in Visual Code and get the same error.
I Build, Rebuild used Debugging, re-open the IDA. So I'm out of options?

Please check the full code [here on github](https://github.com/LucasHartman/WebApp/tree/master/WebApp)

Comment: The right way of adding a package is to use Solution Explorer.  Then right click top line and select Add Project.  Then you need a "using" statement for each library in the namespace.

Comment: Hi, checked your project. 1. Wrong using. You should add namespace, not a concrete class. using WebApp.Model; not using WebApp.Model.Item; 2. Wrong spelling of types instead of IEnumberable should be IEnumerable. Guide, correct - Guid

Comment: After i fixed all errors in code and relaunched VS Code, intellisense for user defined namespaces/classes start working.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Having a working version work as an example helps understanding how to build a project.